# How to handle multiple JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson

I have the following model:

[image: model]

Here is my code (I have removed accessors and useless attributes to increase lisibility):

## A:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "a", schema = "public")
public class A implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference("a")
    private Set<A_B> ABs = new HashSet<>();
}
```

## B:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "b", schema = "public")
public class B implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.b", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference("b")
    private Set<A_B> ABs = new HashSet<>();
}
```

## A_B:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "a_b", schema = "public")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.a",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.b",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "b_id"))
})
public class A_B implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private A_BId pk = new A_BId();

    @OneToOne
    private B b;
}
```

## A_BId:

```java
@Embeddable
public class A_BId implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference("a")
    private A a;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference("b")
    private B b;
}
```

I'm using `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate4` to parse my objects in json.

1. When I parse `A`, I would like to get `B` from `A_B`s without getting `A` from `A_B`s.
2. Inversely, when I parse `B`, I would like to get `A` from `A_B`s without getting `B` from `A_B`s.

With my actual code, all `A_B`s' elements are always `null`. And when I remove `@JsonManagedReference("b")` and `@JsonBackReference("b")`, the result of (1) is the one I required, but the result of (2) is an infinite recursion

Does someone have an idea about my issue? Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a final answer but this is the closest solution

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1091

Adding this tag for every class of the problem

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public class A {